# Property of central product of components

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was reading *The Theory of Finite Groups* by Kurzweil and Stellmacher, and in the section about components of groups they stated that if $E(G)$ is the subgroup generated by all the components $K_1, K_2 \dots K_n$, then it is the central product of the components and $Z(E(G))=Z_1Z_2\dots Z_n$ where $Z_i=Z(K_i)$.  They did not give a detailed proof, but rather cited some earlier results to prove this.  I managed to work out a proof on my own, but it does not seem to depend on the fact that the $K_i$ are components of $G$.  So my question is if this is a property that holds for all central products, or is the quasisimple property needed (in which case my proof is flawed)?

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit it

Comment: You have to prove that it is a central product i.e. that $[K_i,K_j] = 1$ when $i \ne j$, and I would expect the proof of that to use the fact that the $K_i$ are quasisimple. The statement about the centre follows from that.

Comment: Ah that is true, I was just wondering because I did not think that the proof would be so easy but on second thought it requires the rather nontrivial property of components commuting with each other.